# Distance word problem - unknown speeds

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

Suppose two people start at points $A,B$ and move towards each other. The first time they meet is $60$ meters away from $A$ and the second time they meet is $75$ meters away from $B$. What's the distance between $A$ and $B$?

I think I'm missing something very simple here, but I don't know what...

Comment: Are they just going back and forth between $A$ and $B$?

Comment: @John yes, they are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $x_A(t)$ be the distance that the person starting at $A$ has walked after time $t$. Let $v_A$ be his speed. Similarly with $B$. They meet at $t=t_1$. Here we have 
$$x_A=v_At_1=60 \quad \text{and} \quad x_B(t_1)=v_Bt_1=|AB|-60.$$

Try writing down the equations for the second encounter. If it is still causing you trouble, let me know.

Comment: I calculated that the difference between the distances traveled *between encounters* is $30$, and I'm sure $|AB|=60+75-30=105$, but I just don't know how to explain why...

Comment: @combinarcotics Great! Try using the formulas/the approach I provided to systematize your thinking.

Comment: I definitely will, but it feels like there should be an easy "word" justification... like physicists use..

Comment: @combinarcotics Haha, lol, maybe there is, but I'm not seeing it (I'm a physicist, albeit no Von Neumann!) ;P

Comment: I don't see how to solve this systematically using equations :(

Comment: @combinarcotics Do you understand the equations I wrote down? If not, what part was confusing?

Comment: I do and I think if the second meeting time is $t_2$ then $x_A(t_2)=|AB|+75$ and $x_B(t_2)=2|AB|-75$, but what now?

Comment: @combinarcotics Great job! First write $x_A=v_At$ for both times (and also for $B$). Now you want isolate $|AB|$, but without it being a function of either $t_1,t_2,v_A$ or $v_B$, so you need to use all your equations to get rid of those. You can start by dividing the four equations you have by the time in them (i.e., $t_1$ for the first two, and $t_2$ for the last two), to get two equations for $v_A$ and two for $v_B$. Now you can set those two pairs equal to each other, whereby the speeds have been eliminated. Now all you have to do is eliminate the times as well, and solve for $|AB|$.

Comment: But I have two equations in three variables $t_1,t_2,|AB|$ - how can I eliminate?

Comment: @combinarcotics Divide the pair of equations so that the times cancel.

Comment: Got it - there's an easy quadratic equation with one root zero. Thank you very much!

Comment: @combinarcotics Glad to have helped! :) If you like, you can "accept" the answer by clicking the tick that is located under the up/down vote buttons. This will take the question off of the unanswered-list and give a boost in reputation to the answerer (and yourself). Note that you can only accept one question per answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a easier solution:

Let $u,v$ be the speed of the person starting from points $A,B$ respectively. Let the distance between $A$ and $B$ be $d$.

The idea is at the 1st encounter, the two people *together* traveled $d$ and it took them  time $\frac{d}{u+v}$. We also know this is equal to the time for person 1 to travel 60, $\frac{60}{u}$.

At the 2nd encounter, the two people together traveled $3d$ at time $\frac{3d}{u+v}$. This also equals the time for person 1 to travel $d+75$, $\frac{d+75}{u}$.

We know the time for the 2nd encounter $\frac{3d}{u+v}$ is 3 times the time for the first encounter $\frac{d}{u+v}$. Hence,

$$3*\frac{60}{u} = \frac{d+75}{u}$$

Solving for $d$ gives us $d=105$. Note, no quadratic root finding involved.